# Web app - catering for smart phones and desktops

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, smartphone

I am designing a simple online shop application.

For an initial pilot I would like to avoid having to create a seperate UI for smart phones and desktop browsers.

As such I am looking to find out if there is something pragmatic that can be done to cater for both in the one UI e.g. perhaps if I am judicious about the design are there Jquery plugins/other options for having a one size fits all solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into responsive design. http://www.html5boilerplate.com offers a responsive template you can start with, Twitter Bootstrap and other CSS frameworks also offer you options for creating @media-query based layouts that modify based on the size of the display.

Answer (score 2):

Your describing a responsive layout.  Try Twitter Bootstrap to get your toes wet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at [Responsive Design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design):

[Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)

[Scott Hanselman on Responsive Design](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EasyStepsToAMobilefriendlyResponsiveDesignWithAnEmbeddedYouTubeVideoAndAFluidResize.aspx)